# Find all analytic functions $f: \mathbb{C} \backslash\{3\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $|f(z)| \leq \frac{\left|(z-2)^{2}\right|}{|z-3|}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, laurent-series, analytic-functions

This is a question on one of my homework sheets for a complex function theory module on my maths MSc.

I believe I need to use the Laurent series for $f(z)$ around 3 here, so I wrote $f(z)$ as:

$$f\left(z\right)\ =\ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n\left(z-3\right)^n$$

And then I used the integral representation of the coefficients:

$$a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{S_p^+\left(3\right)}^{ }\frac{f\left(z\right)}{\left(z-3\right)^{n+1}}dz$$

So this would mean that we have:

$$f\left(z\right)\ =\ \left|\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{S_p^+\left(3\right)}^{ }\frac{f\left(z\right)}{\left(z-3\right)^{n+1}}dz\right)z^n\right|\le\frac{\left|\left(z-2\right)^2\right|}{\left|z-3\right|}$$

I somehow need to determine how many coefficients of the Laurent series are nonzero, but I'm kind of stuck on where to go next. I noticed that by Cauchy's nth Derivative Formula that, since

$$f^n\left(3\right)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{S_p^+\left(3\right)}^{ }\frac{f\left(z\right)}{\left(z-3\right)^{n+1}}dz$$

I guess that means we could write $a_n=\frac{f^n\left(3\right)}{n!}$, but I don't know if that's helpful here.

Comment: why not take $g(z)=(z-3)f(z)$ which is entire (bounded near $3$) and satisfying $|g(z)| \le |z-2|^2$ hence it's a polynomial of degree at most $2$ with a double root at $2$ etc

Answer (score 3):

Clearly,
$$
g(z)=(z-3)f(z),
$$
has a removable singularity at $z=3$, and hence it is extended to an entire function. Call its extension $g$ as well.

Then
$$
|g(z)|\le |z-2|^2, \quad \text{for all $z\in\mathbb C$}.
$$
If we set
$$
h(z)=\frac{g(z)}{(z-2)^2}, \quad z\ne 2,
$$
then $|h(z)|\le 1$, for all $z\ne 2$, and therefore $h$
has a removable singularity at $z=2$. Hence $h$ is extended to an entire function, which is bounded by $M=1$. Therefore, $h$ is constant, $h(z)\equiv c$, with $|c|\le 1$.

Consequently
$$
f(z)=\frac{c(z-2)^2}{z-3}, \quad z\in\mathbb C\setminus\{3\}.
$$
for some $c$, with $|c|\le 1$.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! Can I ask why $|g(z)| \leq|z-2|^{2}, \quad \text { for all } z \in \mathbb{C}$ implies that $h(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z=2$? I'm struggling to see how it follows

Comment: @JulietTreip See  the new version of my answer.